# Can a Neural Network learn a simple interpolation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I’ve tried to train a 2 layer neural network on a simple linear interpolation for a discrete function, I’ve tried lots of different learning rates as well as different activation functions, and it seems like nothing is being learned!

I’ve literally spent the last 6 hours trying to debug the following code, but it seems like there’s no bug! What's the explanation?

```py
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset
    import os
    import torch
    import numpy as np
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.optim as optim
    import random

    LOW_X=255

    MID_X=40000

    HIGH_X=200000


    LOW_Y=torch.Tensor([0,0,1])
    MID_Y=torch.Tensor([0.2,0.5,0.3])
    HIGH_Y=torch.Tensor([1,0,0])

    BATCH_SIZE=4

    def x_to_tensor(x):
        if x<=MID_X:
            return LOW_Y+(x-LOW_X)*(MID_Y-LOW_Y)/(MID_X-LOW_X)
        if x<=HIGH_X:
            return MID_Y+(x-MID_X)*(HIGH_Y-MID_Y)/(HIGH_X-MID_X)
        return HIGH_Y


    class XYDataset(Dataset):
        LENGTH=10000
        def __len__(self):
            return self.LENGTH


        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            x=random.randint(LOW_X,HIGH_X)
            y=x_to_tensor(x)
            return x,y




    class Interpolate(nn.Module):

        def __init__(self, num_outputs,hidden_size=10):
            super(Interpolate, self).__init__()
            self.hidden_size=hidden_size
            self.x_to_hidden = nn.Linear(1, hidden_size)
            self.hidden_to_out = nn.Linear(hidden_size,num_outputs)
            self.activation = nn.Tanh() #I have tried Sigmoid and Relu activations as well
            self.softmax=torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)

        def forward(self, x):
            out = self.x_to_hidden(x)
            out = self.activation(out)
            out = self.hidden_to_out(out)
            out = self.softmax(out)
            return out


    dataset=XYDataset()

    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                              shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

    criterion= nn.MSELoss()


    def train_net(net,epochs=10,lr=5.137871216190041e-05,l2_regularization=2.181622809797563e-12):
            optimizer= optim.Adam(net.parameters(),lr=lr,weight_decay=l2_regularization)
            net.train(True)
            running_loss=0.0
            for epoch in range(epochs):

                for i,data in enumerate(trainloader):
                    inputs,targets=data
                    inputs,targets=torch.FloatTensor(inputs.float()).view(-1,1),torch.FloatTensor(targets.float())
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    outputs=net(inputs)
                    loss=criterion(outputs,targets)
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()
                    running_loss+=loss.item()              
                    if (len(trainloader)*epoch+i)%200==199:
                        running_loss=running_loss/(200*BATCH_SIZE)
                        print('[%d,%5d] loss: %.6f ' % (epoch+1,i+1,running_loss))
                        running_loss=0.0



    for i in range(-11,3):
        net=Interpolate(num_outputs=3)
        train_net(net,lr=10**i,epochs=1)
        print('for learning rate {} net output on low x is {}'.format(i,net(torch.Tensor([255]).view(-1,1))))
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Softmax` for this thing?  `0<=Softmax(x)<=1` for all `x`

Comment: In the function that we want to learn, There are 3 outputs which always sum exactly to 1 for all x (check out x_to_tensor). Softmax's outputs always sum to 1 as well, so that's why.

Comment: epochs=10 seems rather low, as is the learning rate.  Is the loss after each epoch decreasing?

Comment: If you run this code (or look at the very bottom), you can see that I've tried learning rates from 10^3 all the way down to 10^(-11). I've tried 80 epochs as well, and each epoch consists of 10,000 examples. To my mind,for this simple function that's a lot! The loss doesn't seem to go down,no. And I've checked the code many times, I am pretty sure it's not a bug. Feel free to run the code-It's straightforward to change it- you will be able to see (amongst other things) the loss...

Comment: the range of your input seems quite large. Have you considered scaling the inputs to -1, 1 range? have you tired inserting batchnorm layers?

Comment: "planes" is undefined....

Comment: @Scott I'm sorry,my bad-should have been num_outputs, I've fixed that in the question itself and ran it just to make sure-should be good now

Comment: @Shai I'll try to normalize the input and see if that helps. Same thing for BatchNorm- but normalizing the inputs seems like a bigger problem actually.

Comment: @Shai Bullseye dude, I feel silly failing at the ABC of NN lol... but anyways, the problem was not normalizing the inputs. I've normalized it to [0,1] and now it works. It's crazy that before normalizing there wasn't even a signal! Thank you! You can publish that as an answer if you want the upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your problem is quite simple, it is poorly scaled: `x` ranges from 255 to 200K. This poor scaling leads to numerical instability and overall makes the training process unnecessarily unstable.
To overcome this technical issue, you simply need to scale your inputs to `[-1, 1]` (or `[0, 1]`) range.

Note that this scaling is quite ubiquitous in deep-learning: images are scaled to `[-1, 1]` range (see, e.g., [`torchvision.transforms.Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize)).
To understand better the importance of scaled responses, you can look into the mathematical analysis done in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Perform a simple interpolation with a NN however you have to consider the following:

I would recommend the following settings:

1. For an activation function: for a simple interpolation a identity activation function can turn the NN as a Linear Regressor which may generalize well. However you should consider Rectified Linear Unit (Relu) for big data and Logistic/Tanh for regular size data as other options.
2. In case of big amounts of data I would select an iterative optimizer for weights as simple gradient descent or Adam. On the other hand if you got few data I would use a Newton approximation LBFGS since you will get a good approximation at weights in a reasonably lower computational time.
3. Vary the number of neurons in each layer and number of layers performing batch learning to seek better approximations.